# Change login page in Spring security plugin using grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I install Spring security plugin using following way:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
```

Add following line in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/'
```

But I can't redirect to home page using this.

So In which place I am wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/' 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/'
```

In this. You set your home page how url for login. Now you must send login data to url: '/'
Just erase this fields or use another.

Comment: In my UrlMappings.groovy file  I set "/"(controller:"/dashboard") .
But page is not redirect.

Comment: becouse you mapping spring security to this url. Just remove or edit two last lines in your question and try again

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security uses "/" as default success Uri and "/login/ajaxSuccess" for ajax authentication. The auth.loginFormUrl gives login page url whose value by default is "login/auth". The security plugin uses LoginController.groovy class to manage login authentication.

You have defined controller "dashboard" for "/" which in your case is same  for both loginFormUrl and login success Url(by default).So you need to implement logic to redirect to different location in dashboard controller. Or you can use different URL for loginURL and successUrl.

Define controller class and implement logic according to role

```
def springSecurityService

def index() {
    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    if (user) {
        if (user.authoritiesInString.contains(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN)) {
            render "admin login "
        } else if (user.authoritiesInString.contains(Authorities.ROLE_USER)) {
            render "user login"
        }
    } else {
        redirect(uri: '/login')
    }

}
```

In Your URLmapping.groovy define mapping for "/" which is default success handler.

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/login" controller: 'login', action: 'auth'

    "/" controller: 'main', action: 'index'


}
```

Spring security plugin provides feature to override many url which can be found here http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/urlProperties.html